# Java Generics (working code, but not pretty.. nor efficient)

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, set

So this abomination of code creates arrays based off input from the user. Sample input would be something like "S 4 aba bab baa aab" where:

args[0] = array type (Int, Double, String)

args[1] = length of array

args[2...] = contents of the array

The creation of the arrays in my code is horrible, but I am not quite sure how else to do it while incorporating generics. The point of the code is to be able to pass any of the created arrays to the methods at the bottom, hence generics.

Thanks for any and all input in advance!

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class ArrayGenerics<E> {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    checkUsage(args);
```

My question is here:
I have the loop to fill in the array and call to the methods in each conditional, which makes me think I could rewrite this in such a way that it is not so repetitive.

```
    if (args[0].matches("I|i")) {
        ArrayList<Integer> iL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++) {
            iL.add(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
        }
        System.out.println("Original: " + iL);
        System.out.println("  Unique: " + removeDuplicates(iL));
        shuffle(iL);
        System.out.println("Shuffled: " + iL);
        System.out.println(" Maximum: " + max(iL));

    } else if (args[0].matches("S|s")) {
        ArrayList<String> sL = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++) {
            sL.add(args[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Original: " + sL);
        System.out.println("  Unique: " + removeDuplicates(sL));
        shuffle(sL);
        System.out.println("Shuffled: " + sL);
        System.out.println(" Maximum: " + max(sL));
    } else {
        ArrayList<Double> dL = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++) {
            dL.add(Double.parseDouble(args[i]));
        }
        System.out.println("Original: " + dL);
        System.out.println("  Unique: " + removeDuplicates(dL));
        shuffle(dL);
        System.out.println("Shuffled: " + dL);
        System.out.println(" Maximum: " + max(dL));
    }

}
```

End of code in question

```
public static <E> ArrayList<E> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<E> list) {
    new HashSet<E>(list);
    list = new ArrayList<E>(new HashSet<E>(list));              
    return list;

}

public static <E> void shuffle(ArrayList<E> list) {
    Collections.shuffle(list);
}

public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(ArrayList<E> list) {
    return Collections.max(list);
}

public static void checkUsage(String[] args)
{
    if (args.length < 2) 
    {
        System.out.println("Please supply more than 2 arguments");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    if (!(args[0]=="s") && (args[0]=="S") &&
        (args[0]=="d") && (args[0]=="D") &&
        (args[0]=="i") && (args[0]=="I")){
        System.out.println("Incorrect format of command.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Each conditional fills in the array with the supplied arguments as well as makes calls to the methods. That fact that I make calls to the methods in each of the conditionals makes me think that I could configure the code in a way that I could call the methods after the conditionals in order to not have a repetitive code.    I edited the post to hopefully clarify it a little better.

Comment: If you're looking for feedback on improving already-working code, Stack Overflow is not the right place to come for it.  You should instead submit it to our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Didn't know about that site. Sorry about that! I'll close this out.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best practice, but if you're trying to code-golf this you can shrink it a little:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    checkUsage(args);

    ArrayList<E> array = new ArrayList<>();

    if (args[0].matches("I|i")) 
        for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++) 
            array.add((E) new Integer(args[i]));

     else if (args[0].matches("S|s")) 
         for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++) 
                array.add((E) new String(args[i]));
     else 
         for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++) 
                array.add((E) new Double(args[i]));


    System.out.println("Original: " + array);
    System.out.println("  Unique: " + removeDuplicates(array));
    shuffle(array);
    System.out.println("Shuffled: " + array);
    System.out.println(" Maximum: " + max(array));

}
```

Or with even less efficiency...

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    checkUsage(args);

    ArrayList<E> array = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++)
        if (args[0].matches("I|i"))
            array.add((E) new Integer(args[i]));
        else if (args[0].matches("S|s"))
            array.add((E) new String(args[i]));
        else if (args[0].matches("D|d"))
            array.add((E) new Double(args[i]));

    System.out.println("Original: " + array);
    System.out.println("  Unique: " + removeDuplicates(array));
    shuffle(array);
    System.out.println("Shuffled: " + array);
    System.out.println(" Maximum: " + max(array));

}
```

Comment: I tried something like the top one before and was running into issues. I put this code into my program and got the issue again. With the line "ArrayList<E> array = new ArrayList<>();" I get "Cannot make static reference to non-static type E"

Comment: Mae sure you add the parameter to your main method. `<E extends Comparable<E>>`. (This is a different E.. I probably should have clarified that or used a different parameter)

Comment: I lied. I figured it out. Thanks!